# runtime error on emulator but not on phone nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, emulation

Got my code in a try-catch loop. It runs fine on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S3, but give a runtime error in the Eclipse emulator.

The error appeared after I added a color setting to the method and used a GradientDrawable as the background for my button (even though this seems to work fine at other locations).

I'm totally lost here... Please have a look, THANKS!!

**Code that generates the error**
Note: I put a breakpoint on "return super.onContextItemSelected(item);", runtime error is generated on/after the return statement.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
    int timerLocation = findTimer(item.getGroupId());
    if (timerLocation > -1)
    {
        final MyCountDownTimer selectedFrag = this.myTimersList.get(timerLocation).fragmentRef;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.timer_settings:
                // Open timer specific options menu:
                defaultSettingsMenu(selectedFrag);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    else timerClickScreen.setText("ERROR: timer not found: " + String.valueOf(item.getGroupId()) + ", "+ String.valueOf(timerLocation));

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item); 
}
```

**Main method:**

```
private void defaultSettingsMenu(MyCountDownTimer selectedFragIN)
{
    try
    {
        final MyCountDownTimer selectedFrag = selectedFragIN;

        final Dialog dialog_settings = new Dialog(this);
        dialog_settings.setContentView(R.layout.timer_set_options);

        if (selectedFrag == null) dialog_settings.setTitle(R.string.default_settings_for_timer);
        else dialog_settings.setTitle(R.string.timer_settings);

        if (selectedFrag == null)
        {
            // Set title color:
            dialog_settings.getWindow().setTitleColor(getDefaultColor());
            // Set divider color:
            int dividerTop = dialog_settings.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
            View divider1 = dialog_settings.findViewById(dividerTop);
            divider1.setBackgroundColor(getDefaultColor());
        }
        else
        {
            // Set title color:
            dialog_settings.getWindow().setTitleColor(selectedFrag.getTimerColor());
            // Set divider color:
            int dividerTop = dialog_settings.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
            View divider1 = dialog_settings.findViewById(dividerTop);
            divider1.setBackgroundColor(selectedFrag.getTimerColor());
        }

        final TextView[] settingsItems = new TextView[8];
        settingsItems[0]= (TextView) dialog_settings.findViewById(R.id.timerSettings_item1);
        settingsItems[1]= (TextView) dialog_settings.findViewById(R.id.timerSettings_item2);
        ...

        final Spinner[] settingsSetting = new Spinner[7];
        settingsSetting[0]= (Spinner) dialog_settings.findViewById(R.id.timerSettings_setting1);
        settingsSetting[1]= (Spinner) dialog_settings.findViewById(R.id.timerSettings_setting2);
        ...

        settingsItems[0].setText(R.string.settings_title1);
        settingsItems[1].setText(R.string.settings_title2);


        // Give some padding on left side:
        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) settingsItems[i].setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);

        // Create menu items:
        final String[] items1 = new String[]{getString(R.string.settings_menu1_item1), getString(R.string.settings_menu1_item2), getString(R.string.settings_menu1_item3), getString(R.string.settings_menu1_item4)};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items1);
        settingsSetting[0].setAdapter(adapter1);

        if (selectedFrag == null) settingsSetting[0].setSelection(defaultTimerSettings.OnTapResponseValue.ordinal());
        else settingsSetting[0].setSelection(selectedFrag.getTapBehavior().ordinal());

        <... MORE SAME CODE HERE ...>

        SpinnerColorSelector mySpinnerColorSelector = new SpinnerColorSelector(this);
        settingsSetting[6].setAdapter(mySpinnerColorSelector);
        if (selectedFrag == null) settingsSetting[6].setSelection(findIntArraylist(mySpinnerColorSelector.colors, defaultTimerSettings.colorTimer));
        else settingsSetting[6].setSelection(findIntArraylist(mySpinnerColorSelector.colors,selectedFrag.getTimerColor()));

        dialog_settings.show();

        Button cancelButtonOptions = (Button) dialog_settings.findViewById(R.id.buttonTimerCancelOptions);

        int[] gradientColors = new int[3];
        if (selectedFrag == null) gradientColors = generateGradientColors(getDefaultColor());
        else gradientColors = generateGradientColors(selectedFrag.getTimerColor());
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            GradientDrawable gdDefault = new GradientDrawable();
            gdDefault.setColors(gradientColors);
            gdDefault.setCornerRadius(10);
            gdDefault.setStroke(1, Color.GRAY);
            cancelButtonOptions.setBackground(gdDefault);
        } else {
            // Fallback for APIs under 16.
            GradientDrawable newGdDefault = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, gradientColors);
            newGdDefault.setCornerRadius(10);
            newGdDefault.setStroke(1, Color.GRAY);
            cancelButtonOptions.setBackgroundDrawable(newGdDefault);
        }
        // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        cancelButtonOptions.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Close dialog
                dialog_settings.dismiss();
            }
        });

      <...REMOVED TESTED CODE...>

                }
                // Close dialog
                dialog_settings.dismiss();
                //selectedFrag.setTimerValue(hour*60*60*1000+minutes*60*1000+seconds*1000); 
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("MainActivityError: defaultSettingsMenu function: Error in dialog function.",Log.getStackTraceString(e)); 
    }
}
```

**mySpinnerColorSelector CLASS:**

```
public class SpinnerColorSelector extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Integer> colors;
    Context context;

    public SpinnerColorSelector(Context context) 
    {
        this.context=context;
        colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#57b947")); // Time Boss green
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#33B5E5")); // Android blue
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#0099CC")); // blue
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#AA66CC")); // purple light
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#9933CC")); // purple
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33")); // orange light
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#FF8800")); // orange
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#FF4444")); // red light
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#CC0000")); // red
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return colors.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) 
    {
            return colors.get(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return arg0;
    }
    @SuppressLint({ "ViewHolder", "InflateParams" }) @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        TextView txv=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        txv.setBackgroundColor(colors.get(pos));
        txv.setTextSize(20f);
        txv.setTextColor(colors.get(pos));
        txv.setText(colors.get(pos).toString());
        return view;
    }

}
```

**LOGCAT OUTPUT:**

```
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698): Process: com.xpresspe.stopwatch, PID: 1698
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6113)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6408)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild(Spinner.java:632)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:585)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.Spinner.getBaseline(Spinner.java:431)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1089)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformWidth(LinearLayout.java:940)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:920)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2321)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1145)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1340)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1032)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
09-24 15:14:24.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1698):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me...

Comment: What is the line that's giving you the error?

Comment: Hi Pedro,

Not sure.

The error occurs when I go to the context menu and select the options. This loads the defaultSettingsMenu with the timer that generated the trigger (for the context menu).

This is tested before and works fine.

I can do this repeatedly, 
HOWEVER, if I change the COLOR the timer does respond correctly (the timer color changes), 
BUT if I try to open the defaultSettingsMenu again the nullpoint exception is generated.

This only occurs on the Emulator and not on my Phone (runs fine there).

Does this help?

Comment: I suggest you place a breakpoint on the first line of defaultSettingsMenu and run the program on Debug mode and go through it line by line to see what is causing the problem.

Comment: Added breakpoint. The return statement in the function: onContextItemSelected (now added to question) apparently gives the error...

Comment: I feel it may be a problem with my custom Spinner, but can't figure it out yet...

Answer (score 0):

In the SpinnerColorSelector class, I changed:

```
view=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
```

To:

```
view=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
```

And the runtime error is gone! It now runs on the emulator without problems... Still strange that try-catch didn't catch this one (maybe because the dialog is made at a later time under the hood). Anyway, back to being a happy puppy!!

This also got rid of the @SuppressLint({ "InflateParams" })